# Can I use 2 entities/models with 1 controller?

Tags: spring-boot, mongodb-query

I have a spring boot project with mongodb that has 2 databases connected. I am trying to use 2 entities/models for each database. So that each database has 2 entites/model 2 repositories and 1 controller. Is that possible? If yes, how can I implement it? I was able to implement 2 databases, but can't use 1 controller to query two repositories.

I had the following code:

```
public class firstCollection{
@Id
String id;
@Field("fname")
String firstName;
@Field("lname")
String lastName;
}
```

and the second entity

```
public class secondCollection{
@Id
String id;
@Field("fname")
String firstName;
@Field("lname")
String lastName;
}
```

The repositories

```
public intereface firstCollectionRepository extends MongoRepositories<firstCollection,String>{
@Query(value = "{'lname' : ?0}")
List<firstCollection> findName(String name);
}
```

```
public intereface secondCollectionRepository extends MongoRepositories<secondCollection,String>{
@Query(value = "{'lname' : ?0}")
List<secondCollection> findName(String name);
}
```

The controller

```
public class controller {
@Autowired
firstCollectionRepository firstRepo;
@Autowired
secondCollectionRepository secondRepo;

@RequestMapping(value = "/name")
public String getName()
{
  firstRepo.findName("john");
  secondRepo.findName("john");
  return "index"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create an object that contains that includes the two other objects you want.

So it would be

```
Entity1 {
 ...
}

Entity2 {
...
}

Model {
 Entity1
 Entity2
}

ControllerPostMapping(Model model) {

}
```

Or you can also look into [DTO's](https://auth0.com/blog/how-to-automatically-map-jpa-entities-into-dtos-in-spring-boot-using-mapstruct/#Defining-the-DTOs)